# How can I remove TypeScript warning for 3rd party code in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio

I get thousands of warnings about my JS files from 3rd parties (TS1002, etc.). We have no Typescript in our project.

I've tried adding `<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>` to my CSProj files which had no effect.

Then I added a tsconfig.json with

```
//tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "checkJs": false
  }
}
```

This did get rid of the warnings but now I get an error for each project: `TS18003 No inputs were found in config file...`

I've checked that my compile on save in the settings is off as well as ESLint.

Anyone know how to suppress these errors, preferably for certain directories.

Comment: What typescript / js related plugins do you have enabled?

Comment: Under Extensions and Updates I have nothing Typescript related.

Comment: Jason, the JavaScript support native VSCode depends on the TypeScript language service.       We might be able to help more with a specific example of the problem.   If possible, create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I'm back to working from home again and realize that this only happens from this machine.

I compared every setting until I gave up. But upon running into an issue with NPM I checked my "External Web Tools" settings and $(PATH) was not the top entry on my home machine.

I changed this and restarted and I no longer have the TypeScript warnings!